# Is it possible to mail google maps using php

Tags: php, google-maps

I have code for finding source and destination in google map. Is it possible to mail that map to a specific mail id using  php code . please help me
           thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to mail a *link* to a Google Map - just put the link into the E-Mail.

Other than that, I don't think you will be lucky. Google Maps uses extensive scripting. Scripting is not supported in E-Mails.

Google Maps has a [static maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) that creates images, but I don't think they do directions on that - and distributing the generated images via E-Mail would probably violate their terms and conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Google maps can be built from their URL. The maps page takes certain variables form the url and uses them to calculate the entire directions. All you have to substitute your locations and way points and any other more advanced options (avoid motorways etc.) and mail that link.

example (guess the location :p ):

http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?hl=en&q=edinburgh+to+london&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1148&bih=766&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=wl

**Edit:** P.S Lat and Lng Values also work in URL